# R rounding error versus C++ rounding error

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I wrote a code in R which took two numeric vectors (values and weights) as inputs and produced a weighted Gini, a weighted variance and a difference of two weighted means (population one are data rows less than or equal to Revision and population two are data rows greater than Revision).  This in turn sat inside a loop that ran 100,000 times.  It was slow.  So I decided to try using Rcpp to perform this task using C++ code instead.  Below is the .cpp file I made in RStudio which defines the function.

I have another code to test it.  It works spot on with simple input vectors.  But when I use larger input vectors it does not work.  I believe the problem has something to do with rounding errors as the input vectors become large.  If so, how can I deal with this problem?  Can I trust the R function which I am comparing my function to?  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

I include the .cpp file and the test file below that.

The .cpp program:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector GetMeasures(const std::vector<double>& Frequency, 
                const std::vector<double>& Value, int Revision) {

long double WeightedSum = std::inner_product(Frequency.begin(), Frequency.end(), Value.begin(), 0);
int N = std::accumulate(Frequency.begin(),Frequency.end(),0);
long double mu = WeightedSum / N;

long double sumOfDifferences=0;
for(int j=0; j<Value.size(); ++j){
  for(int i=0; i<Value.size(); ++i){
    sumOfDifferences=sumOfDifferences+abs(Value[i]-Value[j])*Frequency[i]*Frequency[j];
  }
}
long double M = sumOfDifferences / pow(N,2);
long double Gini = M / (2 * mu);

double SumOfSquares = 0;
for(int i=0; i<Value.size(); ++i){
    SumOfSquares=SumOfSquares+(pow((Value[i]-mu),2)*Frequency[i]);
  }
double Variance = SumOfSquares / (N - 1);

double WeightedSum1 = std::inner_product(Frequency.begin(), Frequency.begin()+Revision, Value.begin(), 0);
int N1 = std::accumulate(Frequency.begin(),Frequency.begin()+Revision,0);
double mu1 = WeightedSum1 / N1;
double WeightedSum2 = std::inner_product(Frequency.begin()+Revision, Frequency.end(), Value.begin()+Revision, 0);
double N2 = std::accumulate(Frequency.begin()+Revision,Frequency.end(),0);
double mu2 = WeightedSum2 / N2;
double Difference = mu1 - mu2;

Rcpp::NumericVector output(3);
output[0]=Gini;
output[1]=Variance;
output[2]=Difference;
return output;
}
```

The test program:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(ineq)

a=c(1,2,3,4)
b=c(5,6,7,8)

with(Lc(a,b), abs(1 - sum(diff(p) * (L[-1] + L[-length(L)]))))
wtd.var(b,weights=b)
wtd.mean(a[1:2],b[1:2])-wtd.mean(a[3:4],b[3:4])

GetMeasures(a,b,2)

a=c(0.07418378, 0.07426745, 0.07435280, 0.07443986, 0.07452865, 0.07461923, 0.07471161, 0.07480584,
0.07490196, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000,
0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000,
0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000,
0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000)

b=seq(from=1400, to=1400/40, by=-1400/40)

with(Lc(a,b), abs(1 - sum(diff(p) * (L[-1] + L[-length(L)]))))
wtd.var(a,weights=b)
wtd.mean(a[1:10],b[1:10])-wtd.mean(a[11:40],b[11:40])

GetMeasures(a,b,10)
```

Test code output:

```
> a=c(1,2,3,4)
> b=c(5,6,7,8)
> 
> with(Lc(a,b), abs(1 - sum(diff(p) * (L[-1] + L[-length(L)]))))
[1] 0.2274725
> wtd.var(b,weights=b)
[1] 1.261538
> wtd.mean(a[1:2],b[1:2])-wtd.mean(a[3:4],b[3:4])
[1] -1.987879
> 
> GetMeasures(a,b,2)
[1]  0.2274725  1.2615385 -1.9878788
> a=c(0.07418378, 0.07426745, 0.07435280, 0.07443986, 0.07452865, 0.07461923, 0.07471161, 0.07480584,
+ 0.07490196, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000,
+ 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000,
+ 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000,
+ 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000, 0.07500000)
> 
> b=seq(from=1400, to=1400/40, by=-1400/40)
> with(Lc(a,b), abs(1 - sum(diff(p) * (L[-1] + L[-length(L)]))))
[1] 0.001816041
> wtd.var(a,weights=b)
[1] 7.659737e-08
> wtd.mean(a[1:10],b[1:10])-wtd.mean(a[11:40],b[11:40])
[1] -0.0004399504
> GetMeasures(a,b,10)
[1]  0.000000e+00  5.638678e-07 -1.185608e-04
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments yet, so i write this as an answer but it's more like a comment.

I don't understand all the code, but I see you are using a few integers and i'm not sure if they are supposed to be always integers or if some rounding is happening here.

Just consider that in c++ integers are always rounded to bottom. A simple trick to round to nearest is to add 0.5 before converting a double/float to an integer:

```
int a = num_to_round + .5;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The only int values are the various sums of the frequency vectors, N, N1 and N2 (N2 is a actually a double by mistake).  The frequency vector is only populated with other integers so I think int should suffice unless I am horribly misunderstanding something about C++.

Answer (score 0):

These two components are a bit suspect:

```
std::vector<double> Frequency; // the declaration
int N = std::accumulate(Frequency.begin(),Frequency.end(),0);
```

A naked `0` is an integer literal in C++, so it appears you are trying to fill an integer by casting doubles to ints, then adding those up.

It would be best to write:

```
int N = static_cast<int>(std::accumulate(Frequency.begin(), Frequency.end(), 0.0);
```

just to be very explicit about the fact that you are converting a sum of `double`s to `int`.

That said, why do you want `N` to be an integer? If you are adding up `double`s and they are intended to add up to some integer value, you probably want to explicitly round to the closest value -- `int` casting always rounds down, which could be very surprising if the result of the summation was `5.99999991587151`.

Comment: The input vector Frequency always contains integers.  So I really should change that declaration to be for integers, not doubles.  That said, I decided to make N, N1 and N2 int because I thought it was good programming form to conserve space and use only what you need.  Is that right?  In any case, I'll try your advice.